# Dagger Inject different Dependency to IntentService in prod & test

Tags: android, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mockito, dagger

Is it possible to inject different object through dagger into android.app.IntentService depending if it is a test or production?

this is mainly the code (simplified) which injects the WebRequest Class into the Service.

```
public class SomeService extends android.app.IntentService {

    @Inject 
    WebReqeust mWebRequest;

    public SomeService(String name) {
        super(name);
        MainApplication.getInstance().inject(this);
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String json = mWebRequest.getHttpString(url);
        JSONObject o = new JSONObject(json);
        DBHelper.insert(o);
    } 
}

@Module(injects = { SomeService.class })
    public class WebRequestModule {

    @Provides
    WebRequest provideWebRequest() {
        return new WebRequest();
    }
}

public class Modules {

    public static Object[] list() {
        return new Object[] {
            new WebRequestModule()
        };
    }
}

public class MainApplication extends Application {

    private ObjectGraph mOjectGraph;
    private static MainApplication sInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        sInstance = this;
        mOjectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(Modules.list());
    }

    public void inject(Object dependent) {
        mOjectGraph.inject(dependent);
    }

    public void addToGraph(Object module) {
        mOjectGraph.plus(module);
    }   
}
```

I would like to write a test which mocks the http response.
I've started with a new Module

```
@Module(
        injects = SomeService.class,
        overrides = true
)
final class MockTestModule {
    @Provides
    WebRequest provideWebRequest() {
        WebRequest webRequest = mock(WebRequest.class);
            when(webRequest.getJSONObjectResponse(contains("/register/"))).thenReturn(
                    new JSONObject(FileHelper.loadJSONFromAssets(this.getClass(),     
                      "mock_register.json")));
            when(webRequest.getJSONObjectResponse(contains("/register_validate/"))).thenReturn(
                    new JSONObject(FileHelper.loadJSONFromAssets(this.getClass(),   
                      "mock_register_validate.json")));
        return webRequest;
    }
}
```

And in the test i tried the following

```
public class RegisterTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        MainApplication.getInstance().addToGraph(new MockTestModule());
        super.setUp();
    }

    public void test_theActuallTest() {
        Registration.registerUser("email@email.com"); // this will start the service
        wait_hack(); // This makes the test wait for the reposen form the intentservice, works fine
        DBHelper.isUserRegisterd("email@email.com"));
    }
```

}

The test is executed successfull (remember, the code is simplyfied and might not compile, just should represent the idea).
However, it still uses the "real" WebRequest Impl., not the Mocked one. I see it in the logs, the proxy and of ourse on the server ...

I did this with RoboGuice in a very similar way and it was working.
But somehow i am not able to get this done with dagger.
(I'm currently evaluating DI Frameworks and this is a "must have")

Answer (score 0):

The `plus` method actual returns the new graph. It doesn't override the original graph.  That being said to accomplish what you want you can simply do this.

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

    ...

    // Mostly used for testing
    public void addToGraph(Object module) {
        mObjectGraph = mOjectGraph.plus(module);
    }   
}
```

This takes the original graph and pluses it with your new module and then simply assigns the new graph to your mObjectGraph reference.

Comment: You are right with the "returns new graph" and i adjusted it, but it does not solve the problem. The test is still using the "production" implementation of WebRequest.

Comment: I'm assuming there's something else not wired correctly somewhere but I can't see anything wrong with your code.  I've personally used this approach with a ServiceTestCase and overriding my graph with a MockModule and everything worked nicely.

Comment: I'll some more research on DI the next days. Once i found out whats wrong, i'll come back to this topic